# How can I make the output of a js not on one single line? How can the output "fit" the input box?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the js code I have written. It generate a random string. I have set this string to be 100 characters long but it doesnt "fit" the input box. The string is just shown on one line.

```html
<div>
  <script>
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    function genPassword() {
      var chars =
        "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
      var passwordLength = 100;
      var password = "";
      for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
      }
      document.getElementById("password").value = password;
    }
    function copyPassword() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("password");
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 999);
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
  </script>
  <div class="konzbox">
    <h2>Zufälliger Konztest-Generator</h2>
    <input
      type="text"
      name=""
      placeholder="Erstelle Konztest"
      id="password"
      readonly
    />
    <table>
      <th>
        <div id="button" class="btn1" onclick="genPassword()">Generate</div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div id="button" class="btn2" onclick="copyPassword()">Copy</div>
      </th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You see here that not all of the output can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1pVo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textarea instead of input for your password.

```js
function genPassword() {
   var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   var passwordLength = 100;
   var password = "";
   for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber +1);
    }
        document.getElementById("password").value = password;

    }
  function copyPassword() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("password");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 999);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  }
```

```html
<div class="konzbox">
  <h2>Zufälliger Konztest-Generator</h2>
  <textarea name="" id="password" cols="30" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
  <table>
    <th><div id="button" class="btn1" onclick="genPassword()">Generate</div></th>
    <th><div  id="button" class="btn2" onclick="copyPassword()">Copy</div></th>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I needed. Is there also a code which enables me to have exactly 10 charactes per line? And have 20lines in total? I've seen you have sm with cols and rows but that doesnt do it, cause I can still adjust the textarea window